# Teradata: Hash string to return string of certain length

Tags: hash, teradata

I need to "sanitize" data for an external report. The input is a string of length 9, and the required output length is 15 characters.
I have tried hash_md5, but that function results in 32 characters. I can't reduce the length of that, because it might introduce the issue of duplicates.

Is there any hash function in Teradata, that allows me to choose the length of the output? Or is there any other approach you can suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: No matter how it's created, every hash with a length of 15 characters might result in collisions, especially when you restrict the characters to 0-9 and A-F. Switching to bytes would be close to the full MD5, 15 of 16 bytes.

Comment: If you're trying to not show data in a report, just don't show it? Replace it with Xs or *s?  In any case, hash_md5 is not going do what you want.

Comment: I have to submit two reports. Those reports tie together with that field. So I can't use Xs. 
@dnoeth: How do I switch to bytes? I'm not quite following. Thanks

Comment: The result of a hash calculation is a series of bytes, in case of MD5 it's 16 bytes. Converted to characters those 16 bytes display as 32 characters. If you return 15 bytes instead of 15 characters it's 15/16 vs. 15/32.